# Unable to get property 'start' of undefined or null reference

Tags: .net, signalr-hub

i have an issue with signalR actually i have data in the code behind but when the code reaches here in view threw the error unable to start a null reference:

```
 $.connection.hub.start().done();
```

im really new in signalR i dont know where to check for this issue

Comment: Most likely `$.connection.hub` is null. You should check initialization code, if there is any, has it been called?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen how can i see what the exact error is?

Answer (score 0):

General flow is like

- get hub
- register method
- start hubconnection

  ```
   $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost/signalr/hubs";
      var hub = $.connection.MyHub; //MyHub is name of our hub on the server side.

      //wire up SignalR
      //register the method which server will call over here
      hub.client.notifyMethod = function (data) {
          //wire the incoming notifications 
          console.log(data);
      };

      //Start hub
      $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
          //once we're done with SignalR we can retrieve connectionid
          console.log($.connection.hub.id);

      });
  ```

To check for any issue

1. Verify hub exists , navigate to http://localhost/signalr/hubs in browser
2. Enable tracing - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/enabling-signalr-tracing#enabling-tracing-in-the-javascript-client

Hope this helps.

Comment: $.connection.hub.url,Unable to set property 'url' of undefined or null reference

Comment: That seems weird , can you please verify library is loaded before calling $.connection.hub.url , if you are using MVC , JS bundles are loaded at the end of document load try to call bundled js at the top of html page. If you could post some code snippet how you are loading signalr library and calling function that might give some insight.